# OneDrive and Multiple File Versions / Revisions

Tags: synchronization, onedrive

Does OneDrive support multiple revisions of files?

In other words, is it possible to "roll back" a file version that got auto-synced by OneDrive Sync app to an earlier copy of the file?

I am trying to sort out a robust archive / backup strategy for my PCs, and I just came across this post from someone effected by the Cryptolocker virus -- which is a very scary scenario!

- [Virus encrypted all Google Drive files - Cryptolocker virus](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/drive/DmZKoIcAPzg)

I could not see any indication of multiple file revisions being available through the OneDrive.conm web page or REST API directly, but i may have missed it.

I suppose I would need to create a backup / archive tool using OneDrive API to add that functionality, or maybe create a mini Git repository locally around those files to allow rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question after some more research and e-mail exchanges with Microsoft:

OneDrive [for Consumers] does not currently support file versioning, but OneDrive for [Small] Business already does, for about the same price point for bulk storage.